# How to return only a specific data from relationships when using $model->load() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using $user->load(['roles', 'expertises', 'languages']) to return data to a front-end made with Vue.

The Vue component I'm using (Treeselect) needs an array of only ID's to load choices made by user.
AFAIK this is not possible ->load(['expertises' => 'myMethod']), this can be useful when you want to return 'expertises' array key, but loading your own filtered data from a custom method.

Please, help me giving some ideas on how to achieve this task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can eager-load specific columns in a `load()` method, but the proper syntax would be:

```php
$user->load(['roles:id,user_id', 'expertises:id,user_id', 'languages:id,user_id']);
```

The problem with that is that you need to include the Foreign Key (I assume `user_id` in this case) to achieve that, which doesn't fit your requirements of only having the ID.

You're probably better off using `->pluck('id')` when passing these to your Components, something like:

```php
$roleIds = $user->roles->pluck('id');
$expertiseIds = $user->expertises->pluck('id');
$languageIds = $user->languages->pluck('id');
// Note: You generally don't need to call `->load()` on a single Model instance; when you try to access them, they will be loaded.
```

Sidenote, you didn't include your components in your question, so I don't know how you're using them.

That being said, you can load those `->pluck()` calls to specific variables, or do it inline for your `vue` components, whatever works best for your use case.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. As you said, this is not returning only Id's. All about the component and frontend framework I'm using is on the question. You point me in a good direction btw.

Comment: I accepted your answer as good because you solved the question I posted on the title, despite the whole question is larger than that and involves more actions. Anyway I solved my own question with a workaround (not the most elegant), using UserResource file to transform the $request['expertises'] to an array of only Id's using a simple foreach loop before being sent to the frontend.

Comment: Glad to hear it! You're free to post a self-answer if you think that will help other people too, or leave it as is; up to you. Happy to help either way though; cheers!